# How to select code from database

Tags: mysql

I hava a database with this codes

indirect customer 
                 Cust-code
    Nursing home NH000001
    Dentist      DN000001
    Other        OT000001

and direct customer
                 Cust-code
    Nursing home NH050001
    Dentist      DN050001
    Other        OT050001

Note after NH there 00 for indirect customer and 05 for direct customers

I need to write a query to get list of direct and indirect customer

```
SELECT * FROM bmwregistration ,corporation_data_entity,category_data_entity,ward_data_entity
                Where occu_corp_id='$corpo'         
                AND occu_division = '$divi' 
                AND bmwregistration.occu_corp_id = corporation_data_entity.corp_id

                AND bmwregistration.occu_ward = ward_data_entity.ward_id
                AND (cust_code LIKE '%BB00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%DP00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%NH00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%PL00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%DN00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%OT00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%PD00%' 
                OR cust_code LIKE '%PN00%' )
```

When executing above query it shows one row 8 times for same cust-code. Can I use group by clause? What is wrong with query?

It select rows with same customer code in eight consecutive lines
cust-code

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3( 8 times same row with cust_id 3)
```

Comment: am afraid the question is not clear!

Comment: JoshL, nneonneo, legoscia, Aleksandr M, David Can you reopen question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with `group by`

```
   SELECT * FROM bmwregistration ,corporation_data_entity,category_data_entity,ward_data_entity
            Where occu_corp_id='$corpo'         
            AND occu_division = '$divi' 
            AND bmwregistration.occu_corp_id = corporation_data_entity.corp_id

            AND bmwregistration.occu_ward = ward_data_entity.ward_id
            AND (cust_code LIKE '%BB00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%DP00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%NH00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%PL00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%DN00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%OT00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%PD00%' 
            OR cust_code LIKE '%PN00%' ) 
      GROUP BY  bmwregistration
```